# Where does this bottom margin come from?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I'm cramming lots of small line charts onto one single figure. Sometimes I am left with a relatively large bottom margin, depending on my data. This is not specific to subplots but can also happen for only one axes. An example:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.Series([1, 2, 2, 4, 5], index=pd.date_range('2023', periods=5))
df = df.drop_duplicates()        # Without gaps as is well

fig = plt.figure()
plt.subplots_adjust(0, 0, 1, 1)  # No margins
# ... Lots of stuff/subplots might happen here...

df.plot(xticks=[])               # Depending on df, leaves a bottom margin
plt.show()
```

This leaves a large margin at the bottom:

[image: result with margin]

Why is this? Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 2):

After some digging I found the cause myself. It turns out that pandas treats a date x axis special (`format_date_labels`). And unless the date range is completely regular (no gaps), `bottom=0.2` is set explicitly (via `fig.subplots_adjust`). At least when the date gap is in one of the bottom subplots.

This brings a simple workaround:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.Series([1, 2, 2, 4, 5], index=pd.date_range('2023', periods=5))
df = df.drop_duplicates()        # Without gaps as is well

fig = plt.figure()
plt.subplots_adjust(0, 0, 1, 1)  # No margins
# ... Lots of stuff/subplots might happen here...

df.plot(xticks=[])               # Depending on df, leaves a bottom margin
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0)    # Fix!
plt.show()
```

Now the result has no margin as expected:

[image]

I'm unsure whether this behavior is a pandas bug. I thought it would be a good idea to document the workaround. At least for me, as I will probably find it here in the future.